# Show List of User Names in List With Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-controller

I have been having a problem with this for hours now, and I don't know what is wrong. I am trying to make a list of registered users in Laravel but it keeps giving me the error:

> "Undefined variable: users (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laraveltest1\links\resources\views\home.blade.php)"

I have asked around on the Laravel Discord server. We've tried several things with no luck such as changing names and changing up the code.

**Home.blade.php**

```php
@foreach ($users as $user) {
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

}

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();

        return view()-> with ('home', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

I want to have a list, but it gives me an error code stated above.

Comment: You don't appear to have any debugging in there. Does `$users` get set in the controller? Do you have issue connecting to your database? Do you definitely have a table in the DB called `users`?

Comment: What do you mean by setting in the controller? And database is fine. I can login with it. Users table is also in the database @ObsidianAge

Comment: That's not how you use `with`. `return view('home')->with('users', $users)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return view('home', compact('users'));
    }

}
```

And in your view

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Same error :"Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laraveltest1\links\resources\views\home.blade.php)"

Comment: Ok, do this in your controller:   dd($users); And show me what happens

Comment: What do you mean by dd($user), also your new suggestion doesnt work sadly

Comment: dd means Dump and Die, it will print all information that you have in your $users variable

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @LucasPiazzi's answer.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();

        return view('home')->with(['users' => $users]); //take a closer look here
    }
}
```

This is how you pass a variable to a view from controller. now if you add a `{{ dd($users) }}` to the `home.blade.php` you should be able to see a dump of the the `$users` variable